# $N^{1/2}$ and randomness

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, asymptotics, random-walk

I apologize if this question is overly vague, but part of the reason I am asking is because I don't know a more precise way of discussing these ideas.

To state a general question:

> What, if any, connection is there between $O(N^{1/2})$ (or related ideas if big $O$ is not appropriate) and randomness?

Here are a few things which lead me to this vague (sorry!) question:

I was recently talking with an analytic number theorist and he stated something along the lines of

> "Such and such a sequence $\{a_n\}$ has partial sums $\displaystyle\sum_{n<N}a_n$ has asymptotic behavior of $O(N^{1/2})$, so the sequence is essentially random in its distribution."

I would like to understand more what he is referring to.

---

EDIT: I understand that $O(\sqrt N)$ can occur for very deterministic sequences. That was never on question, so I apologize if my quote was misleading. However, I would like to understand what the reason the he would (admittedly imprecisely and incorrect in general) such a comment would be.

---

In other contexts, I have seen $N^{1/2}$ related to random walks and the term "root-mean-squared", but these are unknown waters for me.

There is also the appearance of $O(x^{1/2}\log(x))$ in the Riemann hypothesis as the best error bound for the prime number theorem.

Is this somehow related to the "randomness" $N^{1/2}$ implies in other contexts, with the $\log(x)$ term handling the non-random fact that primes become more sparse for $x>>0$?

Any information about these specific things would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let $a_n=1/\sqrt{n}$ for $n\in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$.  Then $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_n = O(\sqrt{N})$, but certainly $a_n$ is not random.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. No where did I state that I think that randomness should be associated to all such sequences. His comment was based on a heuristic. I was hoping for someone to expound on that heuristic.

Comment: Your sentence "Such and such a sequence $\{a_n\}$ has partial sums $\sum_{n<N}a_n$ has asymptotic behavior of $O(N^{1/2})$, SO the sequence is essentially random in its distribution," is where you stated that you think the essence of randomness should be associated to all such sequences. That was implied by the word "so."  Else, that sentence is misleading.  Example 1:  "The number $25$ factors as $25=5^2$, SO the number 25 is not prime." Example 2: "The function $f(x)=e^x$ is differentiable, SO it is continuous."

Comment: A heuristic is a reasonable (but not necessarily optimal or mathematical) way of doing some task.  If there is some underlying heuristic associated with your question, it would help if you said what task the heuristic is supposed to accomplish, and what that heuristic is. I do not see any mention of a heuristic in your question.

Comment: Theorems about the distribution of primes are often proven by the "method of moments" which is essentially the same method for proving the central limit theorem, where normalizing by the square root of the number of samples is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $X_1, X_2, \dots X_n$ is a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with mean $0$ and [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) $\sigma$. Then the sum $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$ has mean $0$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{n} \sigma$.

There are a large class of results in probability, the simplest being [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) and the most famous being the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), guaranteeing that random variables are not too far from their expected values, where "too far" is measured in terms of the standard deviation. So what the above tells you is that while you might have expected the sum above to vary as much as $O(n)$ from its mean (which occurs if the $X_i$ are not independent but are instead identical, say), in fact independence implies that it only varies about $O(\sqrt{n})$ from its mean. This is a fundamental observation in probability and statistics.

Comment: I see. The context in which the comment was made leads me to think that he was meaning precisely your point about expecting $O(n)$  and finding $O(n^{1/2})$.

Comment: @WSL: I expect so. A basic example where this happens in number theory is in the theory of Gauss sums (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_sum); there you have a sum of $p$ roots of unity that turns out to have absolute value *exactly* $\sqrt{p}$.

Answer (score 2):

if you the average of $N$ independent random variables you get something that has standard deviation of size roughly $N^{-1/2}$. This is the central limit theorem. So the sum has error $O(N^{1/2}).$

The law of iterated logarithms might also be relevant in terms of the rate of convergence of  a sequence to the average.

Comment: This is not the central limit theorem. This is a straightforward calculation. The central limit theorem is a much deeper statement.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how that remark about an $O(N^{1/2})$ sequence being random came about, because you can easily come up with a deterministic (non-random) sequence such that the sum of the first $N$ terms is exactly $N^{1/2}$.

However square root does have some notable importance in randomness. If you have a random sample of $n$ i.i.d. samples from a distribution with standard deviation $\sigma$, then the standard deviation for the mean of these samples (trying to estimate the mean of the distribution) is $\sigma / \sqrt{n}$. For related reasons, if you take a random walk of $N$ steps either $+1$ or $-1$ on the real line, then the standard deviation of your final position relative to your initial position is $\Theta(\sqrt{N})$