Prof. Knuth lecture about $ \pi $ and random maps
In this video, Prof. Knuth talks about an interesting combinatorial problem:
suppose you have a random map $ f\colon \{ 1, 2, 3,\ldots, n  \} \rightarrow \{ 1, 2, 3,\ldots, n  \}$. If you consider the values $( 1, f(1), f(f(1)), \ldots \}$, what is the mean value of the number of steps needed to find one of the previous values a second time?
Knuth sketches that the solution goes like $ 1 + \frac{\sqrt {\pi n}}{2} $, adding that this is a case where $ \pi $ shows up with apparently no connection with the circle.
How is it possible to prove that result? Is there any hidden connection with the circle?

The answer should be $1 + \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}$. You can check that with a simulation. (I don't mean that the simulation is a proof, but that it can give you the right conjecture.)

Thank you for pointing that out

This is related to the Pollard rho method of integer factorization, q.v.

To the second question, it seems the $\pi$ comes from Stirling's approximation, which in turn comes from the Wallis product formula, which can be derived by integrating powers of sine, which is a link to circles.

To sketch the argument we appeal to previous work on the tree function
and random mapping statistics, namely the

Pusieux series for the tree
function
and

Cumulative EGF for cycle size and tail
length.


We get for the former
$$T(z) = 1 -\sqrt{2} \sqrt{1-ez}
+ {\frac{2}{3}} (1-ez) 
-\frac{11 \sqrt{2}}{36} (1-ez)^{3/2}
+ {\frac{43}{135}} (1-ez)^2 
\\ -\frac{769 \sqrt{2}}{4320} (1-ez)^{5/2}
+ {\frac{1768}{8505}} (1-ez)^3 
- \frac{680863 \sqrt{2}}{5443200} (1-ez)^{7/2}
+ \cdots$$
and the latter
$$H(z) = \frac{T(z)+T(z)^2}{(1-T(z))^4}.$$
This cumulative EGF gives precisely the statistic we are trying to
compute.
Substitute the first into the second to get
$$\frac{1}{2 (1-ez)^{2}}
-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{12 (1-ez)^{3/2}}
-\frac{1}{2 (1-ez)}
+\frac{133 \sqrt{2}}{2160 \sqrt{1-ez}}
\\ +\frac{107}{3240}
-\frac{157 \sqrt{2}\, \sqrt{1-ez}}{120960}
+\cdots.$$
We get from the dominant asymptotic (first term)
$$\frac{1}{2} \frac{n!}{n^n} [z^n] \frac{1}{(1-ez)^2}
= \frac{1}{2} \frac{n!}{n^n} (n+1) \exp(n).$$
Using Stirling this becomes
$$\frac{1}{2} (n+1) \exp(n) \frac{1}{n^n} 
\frac{n^n}{\exp(n)} \sqrt{2\pi n}
= \frac{1}{2} (n+1) \sqrt{2\pi n}.$$
We are asking  for cycle size and  tail length starting
from node one.  The EGF  computes the statistic for all
nodes, all mappings. By symmetry and working with grand
averages we may divide by $n$ to get the value for node
one  as none  of  the nodes  are  distinguished in  any
way. We  also need to add  one to account for  the last
step hitting a node that  we have seen before. (This is
one more than  the count of the nodes on  the cycle and
those  on  the tail  where  the  tail length  does  not
include  the  node  that  is shared  with  the  cycle.)
Putting it all together we obtain
$$1 + \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) \sqrt{2\pi n}
\sim 1 + \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}.$$
The values from the cumulative EGF are
$$1, 12, 153, 2272, 39225, 776736, 17398969, 
\\ 435538944, 12058401393, 366021568000, \ldots$$
We get from the second term
$$-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{12} \exp(n) {n+1/2\choose n}
= -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{12} \exp(n) {n-(-3/2)-1\choose n}
\sim -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{12} \exp(n) \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\Gamma(3/2)}.$$
With Stirling and scaling by $n!/n^n$ this makes for a contribution of
$$-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{12} n \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{\pi}/2}
= -\frac{1}{3} n.$$
The third term is easy and we get on scaling again
$$- \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\pi n}.$$
Collecting the three we find for the cumulative statistic
$$\frac{1}{2} n \sqrt{2\pi n} - \frac{1}{3}n 
+ \cdots.$$
Commentary. Here the tail  length does not refer to
the size of the tree attached  at a node that is not on
a cycle but rather the nodes on the path from a node to
its eventual  cycle. The node  where it is  attached to
the cycle  is also the repeat  node that we see  in the
iterates of the map, which are sets of cycles of trees.

Very nice! Do you know any kind of heuristic argument that could be used to conjecture this asymptotic? Maybe even up to a multiplicative constant ?

I guess if you assume that the values of $f$ are completely random you heuristically expect $O(\sqrt{n})$ steps via the birthday paradox.

@QiaochuYuan I found your great answe about the connection between $ O(\sqrt{n})$ and randomness on here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1282655/n1-2-and-randomness. Why do you mention the birthday paradox? Can we directly assume heuristically a behaviour like $ O(\sqrt{n})$ because we take random maps without any further considerations?

@user967210: the heuristic argument I have in mind is very heuristic; it is to assume that all of the values $f(1), f(f(1)), f(f(f(1))), \dots $ are completely random (that is, chosen independently at random). The birthday paradox tells us that that in this probabilistic model the expected time until a collision is $O(\sqrt{n})$, and apparently it is asymptotically $\sqrt{ \frac{\pi n}{2} }$ (almost not but quite what we see here). This is different from the linked question which is about sums of iid samples.

@MarkoRiedel Thank you for your great answer! I add this interesting paper about the subject of random mapping
https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-46885-4_34.pdf


Is there any hidden connection with the circle?

As Marko Riedel's excellent answer shows, the combinatorial details here are complicated but the $\pi$ shows up via Stirling's formula / Stirling's approximation for the factorials
$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n.$$
Here is a much simpler combinatorial situation in which the same $\sqrt{\pi}$ shows up with no apparent connection to the circle, which is also connected to Stirling's formula, and where the relationship to the circle can be explained more conceptually. The question is about flipping coins:

Suppose I flip $2n$ fair coins. What's the asymptotic probability that exactly $n$ of them are heads, as $n \to \infty$?

People are often surprised to learn that this probability converges to $0$. The exact probability can be expressed in terms of binomial coefficients as
$$p_n = \frac{1}{2^{2n}} {2n \choose n}.$$
We can get an asymptotic from here via two applications of Stirling's formula to the numerator and denominator of ${2n \choose n} = \frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}$; various cancellations occur and the result is
$$\boxed{ p_n \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}} }.$$
The appearance of $\pi$ in this expression can be explained conceptually using the central limit theorem, which tells us that as $n \to \infty$ the probability distribution over the number of heads converges to a normal distribution; evaluating the density of this normal distribution at its mean produces the above probability $p_n$. In other words, from the perspective of the central limit theorem the $\sqrt{\pi}$ that appears here is the value of the Gaussian integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \, dx = \sqrt{\pi}.$$
In turn, there is a nice argument explaining where this $\pi$ comes from via squaring the above integral to obtain the 2d integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-x^2-y^2} \, dx \, dy$, then evaluating this integral in polar coordinates to obtain $\pi$. So there is a circle here but it appears quite indirectly, in the fact that the multivariate Gaussian is spherically symmetric so the multivariate Gaussian integral reduces to a (constant) integral over spheres and an integral over radii. (There is also a way to explain the appearance of this $\pi$ in terms of the Fourier transform, using the fact that the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is another Gaussian.)
So, that's the hidden connection to the circle! Many other asymptotic questions in combinatorics also end up having answers that are asymptotically Gaussian, due in some sense to generalizations of the central limit theorem, so $\sqrt{\pi}$'s also tend to appear more generally. I wouldn't be surprised if this specific question was one of them although I'm not familiar with the details.

Thank you! Never thought about the connection with the Gaussian
