Intuitive explanation for why $\pi$ turns up in $\binom{2m}m \sim \frac{4^m}{\sqrt{m\pi}}$
I am aware of the following approximation:
$$\dbinom{2m}m \sim \dfrac{4^m}{\sqrt{m\pi}}$$
Which is equivalent to saying the follwing (as $m \to \infty$):
Given $m$ objects, the number of ways to pick half of those objects is roughly
$$\frac{2^{m+\frac{1}{2}}}{\sqrt{m\pi}}$$
Is there an intuitive/visual explanation as to why $\pi$ turns up here?
Note: I am not looking for a proof of the asymptotic approximation, but more of an intuitive or visual explanation as to why circles are 'involved' in choosing objects.

Doesn't help much but this must be a stirling.

It comes from the central limit theorem. Recently discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4947985/prof-knuth-lecture-about-pi-and-random-maps/4948430#4948430

This may not be fully satisfactory, but one way to interpret your quantity is probabilistically. Namely, you have
$$
\frac{1}{4^m}\binom{2m}{m} =\mathbb{P}\Big\{S_{2m} = m\Big\}
$$
where $S_{2m}$ is a Binomial random variable; for instance, it is the probability that you have $m$ heads in $2m$ independent tosses of a fair coin.
By the central limit theorem, we have the following Gaussian approximation,
$$
\sqrt{8m}\frac{S_{2m} - m}{2m} \approx N(0, 1).
$$
Hence you would expect that your probability is of the order
$$
\mathbb{P}\{|S_{2m} - m| < 1/2\} \approx \mathbb{P}\{|N(0, 1)| < \sqrt{1/(2m)}\} = 2 \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1/(2m)}} \phi(t) \, dt, 
$$
where $\phi$ is the standard Gaussian density. Clearly, we have
$$
2 \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1/(2m)}} \phi(t) \, dt \sim 
2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{2m}}\phi(0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m \pi}}, \quad \mbox{as}~m\to\infty.
$$
Putting the pieces together you will obtain
$$
\binom{2m}{m} \approx 
\frac{4^m}{\sqrt{m \pi}}.
$$
Stated briefly: the factor $\pi$ comes in simply because it is arising from normalization in the Gaussian density.

I think one somewhat simple interpretation connecting it with actual circles would be as follows:
It is a standard calculus result that the $n$-th term of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ is $\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$. For any integer $k$, in the expansion
$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^{k+1}} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{n+k}{k} x^n,
$$
the coefficients near $x^n$ asymptotically grows as $\frac{(n+1)\dots(n+k)}{k!} \sim \frac{n^k}{k!}$. For $k=-\frac{1}{2}$ a similar result should stand:
$$
\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n} \sim  \frac{1}{(-\frac{1}{2})! \sqrt n}
$$
Well, and it so happens that $(-\frac{1}{2})! = \sqrt{\pi}$. Why? The most standard, but not very intuitive explanation is the fact that it is $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$, the value of the Gamma function $\Gamma(z)$ in $z=\frac{1}{2}$.
A more intuitive geometric interpretation is shown e.g. in this video. To describe it very briefly, let $S_n(r)$ and $B_n(r)$ be the area and the volume of the $n$-dimensional sphere and ball correspondingly. Then, you can show
$$\begin{cases}
S_{n-1}(r) &= \frac{n}{r} &B_n(r), \\
S_n(r) &= 2 \pi r & B_{n-1}(r)
\end{cases}
$$
Joined together, these formulas yield
$$
B_n(r) = \frac{2}{n} \pi r^2 B_{n-2}(r),
$$
which expands into
$$
B_n(r) = \frac{2}{n} \frac{2}{n-2}\dots \frac{2}{n-2k} \pi^k r^{2k} B_{n-2k}(r).
$$
Note that you essentially divide by $\frac{n}{2}(\frac{n}{2}-1)(\frac{n}{2}-2)\dots$, which simplifies for even $n$ into
$$
\boxed{B_n(r) = \frac{\pi^{n/2}}{(\frac{n}{2})!} r^n}
$$
Then, it is natural to want for this formula to also work for odd $n$, and the most natural way to do this is by defining $(\frac{1}{2})! = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$, which will also imply the desired $(-\frac{1}{2})!=\sqrt \pi$.
